# How to find a value in each cell in Microsoft Word document?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to see if I can find the value in each cell on a Microsoft Word document between pages 9 and 15. When I get to the part where I am trying to set a range to search in, the `Set Doc = wrdApp.Selection.Range` give me the error:

> Type Mismatch

The Word document cannot be copied into Excel. The word document has to keep its formatting and someone built in some weird headers on each page with merged formatting etc.

```
Sub TFUpdate()
    Dim Wd, FinalRow, TableRow
    Dim wrdApp As Object
    Dim DoC As Range
    
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\kimbersr\Desktop\Word Project\TF1.doc")
    wrdApp.Visible = True
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
    
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    TableRow = 1
    x = 1
    
    For i = 1 To FinalRow
        part = Cells(i, 1).Value
   
    
    wrdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=1, Which:=1, Count:=9
    Set DoC = wrdApp.Selection.Range
    wrdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=14
    wrdApp.DoC.End = wrdApp.Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.End
    
    wrdApp.DoC.Find.Execute FindText:="14-581930L", Forward:=True
    If wrdApp.DoC.Find.Found = True Then

    wrdApp.DoC.Select
    
    End If
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @spencelegend I'm afraid no one will write the code for you, but if you start we can help with any problems you come across. Use the macro recorder to do the process once to see how you would write it them modify the generated code.

Answer (score 1):

Too little information about the format/data of both the Excel and Word files.

Based on the scarce amount of info ...I would probably simply copy the Word data tables to Excel an simply run the VLOOKUP or the INDEX MATCH combo on the 4th column.